# How to disable/enable kendo tooltip

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm using kendo-tooltip to DIV. This is the way I need to show the tooltip. For example:

```
<div kendo-tooltip k-content="some content"></div>
```

Is there anything like k-enabled to disable it in some cases? like:

```
<div kendo-tooltip k-enabled="false" k-content="some content"></div>
```

I tried something but it doesn't work. I use angular JS but no jQuery.

Comment: Lost the div - <div kendo-tooltip k-content="some content"></div>

Comment: As `enable=false` you mean not to show it ?

Comment: Yes, I want to know if there is anything like that I can disable tooltip.

Comment: I can't find anything like that in the docs. You may need to destroy and then recreate the widget, I'm afraid. Perhaps you get a better answer in kendo forums.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to find if there is a good solution.

Comment: Don't you have any solution yet?